# Passing a model to a custom directive - clearing a text input

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What I'm trying to achieve is relatively simple, but I've been going round in circles with this for too long, and now it's time to seek help.

Basically, I have created a directive that is comprised of a text input and a link to clear it.

I pass in the id via an attribute which works in fine, but I cannot seem to work out how to pass the model in to clear it when the reset link is clicked.

Here is what I have so far:

In my view:

```
<text-input-with-reset input-id="the-relevant-id" input-model="the.relevant.model"/>
```

My directive:

```
app.directive('textInputWithReset', function() {

  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      template: '<div class="text-input-with-reset">' +
                  '<input ng-model="inputModel" id="input-id" type="text" class="form-control">' +
                  '<a href class="btn-reset"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>' +
                '</div>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        // set ID of input for clickable labels (works)
        elem.find('input').attr('id', attrs.inputId);

        // Reset model and clear text field (not working)
        elem.find('a').bind('click', function() {
          scope[attrs.inputModel] = '';
        });
      }
  };

});
```

I'm obviously missing something fundamental - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `scope.$apply()` after resetting `inputModel` in your function where you reset the value.

```
elem.find('a').bind('click', function() {
      scope.inputModel = '';
      scope.$apply();
    });
```

Please, read about scope in AngularJS [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of exception handling, executing watches.

I've also added declaring of your `inputModel` attribute in scope of your directive.

```
scope: {
    inputModel: "="
  }
```

[See demo on plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/LzjOOcb6lexjQ18W34RQ?p=preview)

But if you can use ng-click in your template - use it, it's much better.

Comment: If you're going to use `scope.$apply()`, pass it a function containing your logic. Don't just call it empty handed like that, which just turns it into an alias for `scope.$digest()`.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks fakerun - I posted my fix the same time as you posted this - the only difference being that I made use of ng-click in template, as opposed to using the original event handler in the directive in my question.

Comment: @Jay your solution is better, I've been writing about ng-click when suddenly saw your answer. %)

Comment: I'm not sure how this works, since it would seem to suffer from the infamous "scope" problem. That is, the directive creates its own scope as a child of the actual scope. Reading `inputModel` should work fine, since because it doesn't exist in the child scope the original scope is consulted. But attempting to change the value (I thought) should result in a new value being added to the child scope instead of updating the original scope's value. In other words, changing the value should appear to have no effect outside of the directive. What am I missing?

Comment: @AlvinThompson That problem applies to child scopes which prototypically inherit from a parent scope, essentially shadowing the parent scope's variables with their own. If one of those variables is a primitive, assigning something to it would just change the primitive on the child scope, leaving the parent scope's primitive unchanged. That's why it's important to use reference object properties in directive bindings instead of simple primitives. As long as the usage of this directive references an object property, it'll be fine.

Comment: @AlvinThompson I think that you wrote about situation when we declare `inputModel` attribute as value (via '@' annotation), not as object (via '='). If we declare attribute as value, two-way binding won't work and we'll get situation, which you described. I created [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CzTh1l?p=preview) for showing differences.

Comment: @Agop: I see! So it doesn't apply to isolate scope since it doesn't use prototypical inheritance? I think the code in one of my directives just got a **lot** less complicated. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I seem to have fixed it by making use of the directive scope and using ng-click in the template:

My view:

```
<text-input-with-reset input-id="the-relevant-id" input-model="the.relevant.model"/>
```

My directive:

```
app.directive('textInputWithReset', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
      inputModel: '='
    },        
    template: '<div class="text-input-with-reset">' +
                '<input ng-model="inputModel" id="input-id" type="text" class="form-control">' +
                '<a href ng-click="inputModel = \'\'" class="btn-reset"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>' +
              '</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.find('input').attr('id', attrs.inputId);
  };

});
```

Comment: Yes, you've solved it with an isolate scope. See my answer for some more details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already answered your question, but I'll leave my answer here for further explanations in case someone else lands on the same problem.

---

In its current state, there are two things wrong with your directive:

1. The click handler will trigger outside of Angular's digest cycle. Basically, even if you manage to clear the model's value, Angular won't know about it. You can wrap your logic in a [`scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) call to fix this, but it's not the correct solution in this case - keep reading.
2. Accessing the scope via `scope[attrs.inputModel]` would evaluate to something like `scope['the.relevant.model']`. Obviously, the name of your model is not literally `the.relevant.model`, as the dots typically imply nesting instead of being a literal part of the name. You need a different way of referencing the model.

You should use an isolate scope (see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)) for a directive like this. Basically, you'd modify your directive to look like this:

```
app.directive('textInputWithReset', function() {

  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: 'true',
      template: [...],

      // define an isolate scope for the directive, passing in these scope variables
      scope: {
          // scope.inputId = input-id attribute on directive
          inputId: '=inputId',
          // scope.inputModel = input-model attribute on directive
          inputModel: '=inputModel'
      },

      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        // set ID of input for clickable labels (works)
        elem.find('input').attr('id', scope.inputId);

        // Reset model and clear text field (not working)
        elem.find('a').bind('click', function() {
          scope.inputModel = '';
        });
      }
  };

});
```

Notice that when you define an isolate scope, the directive gets its own scope with the requested variables. This means that you can simply use `scope.inputId` and `scope.inputModel` within the directive, instead of trying to reference them in a roundabout way.

This is untested, but it should pretty much work (you'll need to use the `scope.$apply()` fix I mentioned before). You might want to test the `inputId` binding, as you might need to pass it a literal string now (e.g. put `'input-id'` in the attribute to specify that it is a literal string, instead of `input-id` which would imply there is an `input-id` variable in the scope).

After you get your directive to work, let's try to make it work even more in "the Angular way." Now that you have an isolate scope in your directive, there is no need to implement custom logic in the link function. Whenever your link function has a `.click()` or a `.attr()`, there is probably a better way of writing it.

In this case, you can simplify your directive by using more built-in Angular logic instead of manually modifying the DOM in the `link()` function:

```
<div class="text-input-with-reset">
    <input ng-model="inputModel" id="{{ inputId }}" type="text" class="form-control">
    <a href="#" class="btn-reset" ng-click="reset()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>
</div>
```

Now, all your `link()` function (or, better yet, your directive's controller) needs to do is define a `reset()` function on the scope. Everything else will automatically just work!

Comment: See my comment on @Fakerun 's answer. I'm not positive but using isolate scope may not avoid the more fundamental scope issue.